# QGIS 3.8 Batch Processing AttributeError: 'BatchInputSelectionPanel' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I installed the latest version of Qgis (3.8.0). When I try to run batch processing for contours, it gives me this error

[image]

Is anyone else experiencing this? I cant seem to find a quick solution to this problem.

Comment: It's a bug. It is related to this ticket https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29862

Comment: issue created https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30406

Comment: And fixed in new release https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/30407#issuecomment-505751199 !

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great piece of software!